# CentOS rc.local python redirect

Tags: boot, python, centos-6

Scenario is as follows:
I need to execute two python scripts on boot, and redirect their stdout and stderr to a file (each script to a file).

In /etc/rc.local, I've tried (among plenty others) the following:

`# executes, but doesnt redirect
/usr/bin/python3 /root/ping_to_mysql.py > /root/ping_to_mysql.py.log 2>&1 &
/usr/bin/python3 /root/named_to_mysql.py > /root/named_to_mysql.py.log 2>&1 &`

The problem with this is that nothing is logged into the redirected files

How should I accomplish my needs?

System is CentOS 6.9.

EDIT: might be important to say that both python scripts implement execute forever

Thank u so much!

Comment: EDIT: might be important to say that both python scripts implement execute forever

Comment: You didn't describe what actual problems you're having with the above method.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit my question

Comment: Well, I actually did write a pretty explanatory comment: # executes, but doesnt redirect